# Current pagination link doesn't active and Next,Previous doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, pagination

I am trying to implement **PAGINATION or PAGING** while retrieving all posts from database through custom query. I want to display 3 posts on every page. Logic wise it's working fine. Ex. If i click on First page it display 1,2,3 posts and if i click on second page it displays 4,5,6 post.

But problem is - 
1. If i click on any page number link like 1 or 2 or 3 then everytime selected page should be active but in my program always first page number link is active.

2. If i click on Next, it always goes to second page. It should go to next page of current page.
3. Previous link doesn't display.

   ```
   <?php 
   $per_page = 3;
   $page = isset( $_GET['cpage'] ) ? abs( (int) $_GET['cpage'] ) : 0;
   if($page>0)
   $page = $page*$per_page-$per_page;

   $querystr = "
   SELECT $wpdb->posts.* 
   FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
   WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
   AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_edit_last' 
   AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = '1' 
   AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
   AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
   AND $wpdb->posts.post_date < NOW()
   ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC LIMIT $per_page offset $page";

   $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
   ?>
   <?php if ($pageposts): ?>
   <?php global $post;?>
   <?php foreach ($pageposts as $post): ?>
   <?php setup_postdata($post);?>

   <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
   <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent     Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
   <?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
   <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> <!-- by <?php the_author() ?> --></small>
   <div class="entry">
      <?php the_content('Read the rest of this entry »'); ?>
   </div>
   <p class="postmetadata">Posted in <?php the_category(', ') ?> | <?php edit_post_link('Edit', '', ' | '); ?>  
   <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments »', '1 Comment »', '% Comments »'); ?></p>
   ```

**PAGINATION**

```
 <?php 
$querystr2 = "
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_edit_last' 
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = '1' 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_date < NOW()
    ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
 ";
$totalPosts = $wpdb->get_var($querystr2);

echo paginate_links( array(
 'base' => add_query_arg( 'cpage', '%#%' ),
    'format' => '',
    'prev_text' => __('Previous'),
    'next_text' => __('Next'),
    'total' => ceil($totalPosts / $per_page),
    'current' => $page
));

?>
```

Can anyone try to solve this problem or find mistake in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, this link solved all issues regarding display WP post on custom page or template file.

[Custom WordPress loop with pagination](http://callmenick.com/post/custom-wordpress-loop-with-pagination)